# Why is my post-processing calculation using Quantum ESPRESSO not complete after 9 hours?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, computational-chemistry, high-performance-computing, charge-density

I'm working on an i7 laptop with the parallel version of Quantum ESPRESSO (8 processors are running). I ran a post-processing calculation by `pp.x -in ppinput.in > ppoutput.out` and the following input:

```
&INPUTPP
prefix='rocksalt',
outdir='.',
filplot='ppoutputfile.txt',
plot_num=9,
/
&PLOT
nfile=1,
iflag=3,
output_format=3,
fileout='rocksalt.xsf',
e1(1)=1.0,e1(2)=0.0,e1(3)=0.0,
e2(1)=0.0,e2(2)=1.0,e2(3)=0.0,
e3(1)=0.0,e3(2)=0.0,e3(3)=1.0,
x0(1)=0.0,x0(2)=0.0,x0(3)=0.0,
nx=101, ny=101, nz=101,
/
```

The ppoutputfile.txt file was generated very quickly but the rocksalt.xsf file is not generated yet, knowing that it is been 9 hours now and the operation did not complete yet . When I open the ppoutput.out file it is written in the last line  `Writing data to be plotted to file  rocksalt.xsf` .

Is it normal that the calculation still did not complete till now?

Comment: +1. I just want to clarify some things. Since you're using 8 processors, does your laptop have 8 cores, or is it  quad-core (4-core) machine with 8 threads? Could you give us some more information about your laptop (e.g. check the generation of your CPU [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_processors) and the amount of RAM and disk space available, and what other things are running at the same time, perhaps a "system monitor" output would also be helpful to show how much CPU and RAM are currently being used). Have any output files been modified in the last 9 hours? Which & when?

Comment: @NikeDattani  it is  i7- 10th generation. it have 8 cores, 16 threads. My available RAM is 11Gi, and there are no other things running on the computer, i am using it just for running simulations. When I went to sytem monitor-->Processes, under the  process name `pp.x` that i`m running i found that CPU=6% and memory=10.8 MiB (This line is repeated 8 times ).  It is 1day now and the simulation still did not complete yet

Comment: I just realized that the folder that contains the file that i am running is in my 32Gb USB  can that be the cause?

Comment: it is been 2 hours now that I moved the files to the desktop ( without stopping the calculations) . And the calculation did not complete yet

Comment: It would be better to start over with the files on the computer at the beginning (not moved from USB midway). Something seems to have gone wrong and it's a good idea to kill the original job.